# Add a double quote to a string if it doesn't start with a double quote

Tags: awk, text-processing, command-line-tool

I have a text file like this:

```
1,a,"some strings in a pair of double quotes"
2,b,"more strings in a pair of double quotes"
3,c,some messy strings with only right half double quotes"
4.d,"more strings in a pair of double quotes"
```

I tried to use awk with sed to add the missing left double quote to the 3rd line:

```
function addQuote(input) {
 return '"' + input
}    
BEGIN{
   FS=","
}

{
  if ($3~/^"/) s = $3
  else s = addQuote($3)

  print $1,$2,s
}
```

It seems that the `addQuote` function is not working but I don't know how to fix it.

I know in `sed` I can easily add a double quote to begining of a line by doing `sed 's/^/"/' line`, but I don't know how to make it work together with `awk`.
Please kindly help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you fix the process that creates this broken file?

Comment: This is the raw file I get from someone else ...

Comment: Have you told this other person that the file contains errors?

Comment: trouble brewing when the quoted string contains comma!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $3 !~ /^"/{$3="\"" $3} 1'  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$3=$3 !~ /^"/?"\"" $3:$3} 1'  Input_file
```

---

***EDIT:*** As per sir Jonathan's comments in comment section adding following code which will handle 3 cases now, it should add `"` is it not on 3rd field completely, it will add `"` at last of field or starting of field too.

Let's say we have following Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
1,a,"some strings in a pair of double quotes"
2,b,"more strings in a pair of double quotes"
3,c,some messy strings with only right half double quotes"
4,d,"more strings in a pair of double quotes
4,d,more strings in a pair of double
```

now following code may cover all 3 mentioned permutations/combinations here:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$3=$3 !~ /\"/?"\"" $3 "\"":($3 !~ /^\"/?"\"" $3:($3 !~ /\"$/?$3 "\"":$3))} 1'  Input_file
1,a,"some strings in a pair of double quotes"
2,b,"more strings in a pair of double quotes"
3,c,"some messy strings with only right half double quotes"
4,d,"more strings in a pair of double quotes"
4,d,"more strings in a pair of double"
```

Comment: I note that this would convert `1,33,unquoted at all` into `1,33,"unquoted at all`, missing the second double quote.  I'm not sure whether that's a significant problem.  Upgrading the regex to match isn't very hard: `/^[^"].*"$/` would probably handle it, leaving my example input unchanged.  If it should be fully quoted, that can be handled too (slightly differently, but similarly straight-forwardly).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, sure, I have added EDIT solution now sir, which should cover all 3 conditions of not having `"` either in start or in end or not in line itself, kindly do let me know if any further improvements we could do here.

Comment: Avoid negative logic (`!`) since that leads to incomprehensible double-negatives, and avoid redundancy (adding `$3`  on both of the true/false  outcomes of the ternary). Change `$3=$3 !~ /^"/?"\"" $3:$3` to `$3=($3 ~ /^"/ ? "" : "\"") $3`. I also added parens and white space so it won't produce a syntax error in some awks and to improve legibility.

Answer (score 1):

The problems with your addQuote() function:

```
function addQuote(input) {
 return '"' + input
}
```

are that:

1. the string delimiter is `"`, not `'` so you should be using `"\""` instead of `'"'`.
2. the `+` is an arithmetic operator in awk so `"\""` + `input` is telling awk to convert both `"\""` and the contents of `input` to numbers and then add them together. What you want instead is concatenation and there is no specific operator for that in awk - two strings side by side **are** concatenated, e.g. ``"\"" input`.

So if you wrote your function as:

```
function addQuote(input) {
 return ("\"" input)
}
```

it'd do what you want. I added the parens for readability.

Having said that, this might be a better approach as it covers missing quotes at the front and/or the back and ensures that EVERY line gets recompiled which is important if you ever change the OFS value: borrowing the input from @RavinderSing13's answer:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$3); $3="\"" $3 "\""} 1' file
1,a,"some strings in a pair of double quotes"
2,b,"more strings in a pair of double quotes"
3,c,"some messy strings with only right half double quotes"
4,d,"more strings in a pair of double quotes"
4,d,"more strings in a pair of double"
```